# How to find visible order of two elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way of identifying visible order of two elements using js of jquery?

for example: there is a element with `position:fixed` when scrolling the window i need to identify if it is in below the footer `div` or above the footer `div`

some times it look likes this

```
element One
footer div
```

but after scrolling it look likes this

```
footer div
element one
```

I want to identify those two situations separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compare [element.offsetTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop) of both the elements

For example

```
var e1 = document.getElementById("elementOne");
var e2 = document.getElementById("footerDiv");

if ( e1.offsetTop > e2.offsetTop )
{
  //your logic
}
```

jquery equivalent would be [offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) method

```
var e1 = $( "#elementOne" );
var e2 = $( "#footerDiv" );

if ( e1.offset().top > e2.offset().top )
{
  //your logic
}
```

Comment: I think OP is asking of a jQuery solution.

Comment: @IvankaTodorova made relevant changes

Comment: @gurvinder372 nice! +1